# power series with multinomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, analytic-functions, multinomial-coefficients

Is it possible to compute the following power series, in closed form? (where $x$ is sufficiently small)

$$f(x)=\sum_{d=1}^\infty\frac{(3d)!}{(d)!^3}x^d.$$

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Please provide us your work so that we know where you're stuck.  I would like to draw your attention to [this MathMeta.SE question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/290189) about how to ask a good question, in particular the section "Provide Context".  Since you ask for *possibility*, have you used Hadamard's Formula to compute the radius of convergence?

Comment: Yes, it has a positive radius of convergence: r=1/27. I tried the differential equation approach but it didn't quite work. I was wondering if there would be any identity about multinomial coefficients that allows one to compute this.

Comment: Hint: http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/02/01/

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo Thanks! But how can we represent it in closed form?

Comment: Probably something like $\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3};1;27 x\right)-1$...

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo Can this be further simplified to elementary functions?

Comment: For general $x$ I don't think so...

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient sequence is OEIS [A006480](http://oeis.org/A006480) with $a(0)=1$. I suggest adding that term to your summation. As another user commented, it is the power series expansion of $\; _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3};1;27 x\right)$ and is given in the OEIS entry. I regard this as a **closed** form and unlikely to have a simpler form.